# Best CNN architecture for binary classification of small images with a massive dataset

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, image-classification, convolution, accuracy

The title has it all...

Any tip is welcomed.

Should I use a very deep convolutional neural network ?

Use a large amount of filters ?

Parallel layers ?

Dataset examples:

1) "Good"

[image]

2) "Bad"

[image]

Comment: The dataset is made of 2 possible options: 1) An image like any other image you can think of..... 2) the image is "split" in the middle, the left part of the image was taken from 1 place, and the right side was taken from a different place...... so I want the model to tell "Continuous image, or 'cut' in the middle image".

Comment: Can we see some example data please? Also a regular CNN would do fine with this.

Comment: posted examples

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the dataset, there is no single model can be the best.

I would prefer to try a transfer learning Resnet34 or resnet50 with a custom last layer for the number of class of classification.

Comment: Can't transfer learn. The dataset is made of the possible options: 1) An image like any other image you can think of..... 2) the image is "split" in the middle, the left part of the image was taken from 1 place, and the right side was taken from a different place...... so I want the model to tell "Continuous image, or 'cut' in the middle image".

Comment: @MikoDiko in this case, I think a shallow convolution network with 3filters, stride one with one linear layer at the end would work well, it is very easy for a filter to detect the vertical split. I think you don’t even need a max pooling layer.

Comment: Hi BenjiBB, that's what I did, I get ~85% accuracy, but how can I improve it to even 95% ? I tried 3 filters, with\without max pooling, number of Fully-Connected layers, Batch Normalization .. what other trick there is ?

Comment: Hi Miko Diko. Maybe different size of filters and concatenate them together before flattening it to a linear layer.

Comment: Tried this already, any more such ideas ? :)

Comment: Use data augmentation, like rotation, flip or only used the middle part of the picture as input. ;)

Comment: I can make my dataset as big as I want without augmentation